# How do they look <on her> <her on>?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, particle-shift

Considering that

> They look him on as a callous predator. 
>   http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/commentators/matthew-norman-my-sympathy-for-gary-glitter-516838.html

Would this be true:

- How do they look on her? = How do they look her on?
- How do they look on Jane? = How do they look Jane on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From [UsingEnglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/look+on+as.html): << **Look on [someone/something] as** ... Consider, regard

Example:I LOOK ON her AS a close friend.

Notes:

Separable [obligatory] >> I'd say it's not used in the passive ('How do they look on her?'): there's nowhere to put the 'as'. 'What do they look on it as?' sounds pretty outlandish.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the sentence from your cited website is grammatically incorrect. I have researched the phrasal verb *look on* in dictionaries, but I was unable to find an instance when it was split by a direct object.

> A lot of people look on it like that. [Collins English Dictionary]
>
> I look on it as a challenge. [MacMillan Dictionary]
>
> The parents looked on his friend as the more responsible one. [American Heritage Dictionary]

As Mignon Fogarty [carefully points out](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/phrasal-verbs), some phrasal verbs cannot be split like that and must remain in original order to make sense. Here are a few examples:

- We ran out of napkins. (not *We ran napkins out of*)
- I like to hang on to the pole. (not *hang the pole on to*)
- I moved in to my new house. (not *I moved my house in to*)
- BUT: The crook held up the bank. (and *The crook held the bank up*)

Comment: It’s not an indirect object (depending on preferred analysis, it’s either a direct object or a prepositional object), but aside from that, I don’t see why this was downvoted.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet UGH. I meant direct object! I wrote this at, like, 1 in the morning. Let me edit this.

Answer (score 2):

> "They look him on as a callous predator"

appears to be a typographical error. The author almost certainly meant to write

> "They look on him as a callous predator"

Answer (score 0):

**To look on someone as x***= **to see someone as**, ergo: to look on someone as a callous predator.

**They look on him as** a callous predator. [Correction of quotation from the Independent].

Persons or person + verb + look on Persons

COMPARE THAT TO:

**How X looks on someone**, no as. What a person or animal or thing looks like when wearing some thing or when being adorned with some thing.

- How do the trousers look on Jane?
- How do the roses look on the dress?
- How does the tie look on Little Johnny?

Possible answers: The trousers look good on Jane. The roses look terrible on the dress. The tie looks silly on Little Johnny.

How X [something worn on the body] look on + person.

Now try this:

How does John look on Jane? 
He looks terrible today, he's molting.

Trick question: What is John? [joke]

How do the feathers look on the costume? They look great.